# How to increase the width of labels - BlueSky Statistics

Tags: r

In BlueSky Statistics, is there a way to increase the width of the Labels column in Variable view? I am able to select other columns and drag to increase their width but not the Labels column.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible in the current version, why are you looking for this, can you give me an example of what you are trying to achieve. We don't replace the variable name in the output of the analysis like SPSS, the only value in BlueSky Statistics is to see a more friendly name associated with the variable name